# In asp.net MVC5 how do we execute controller code after a View's submit button is clicked?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

VS2013, MVC5, VB

I currently have a page that successfully sends a POST to a payment processor when the user clicks the payment button.  I would like to do some additional actions in code after the request to process the payment is made in that View.  I don't know how to do that.  It may be that I'm thinking of this completely wrong, but that's where I am right now.

I'm assuming I would return to an ActionResult Function to do the final things in code and then go to another View to POST to the payment processor.  I guess I'm asking how to force a View to POST immediately when a Return View() is executed so the user isn't required to click a Payment button again.  Ergo my question about POSTing from a controller, because all I understand how to do is POST from a View.

**Adding to the original post:** Suppose I want to execute Sub ClearCart() (in reality it could be any number of things) after the Payment Submit button is clicked.  So that means I don't want to POST away to the payment processor's website just yet, I want to first run one more piece of code on my end, then POST to the payment processor.  But in order to do that, I only understand how to get back to a controller in order to run Sub ClearCart().  So now after I've run Sub ClearCart(), I have to setup another page with another Payment Submit button, and this time the POST to the payment processor can proceed because I've run the Sub ClearCart().  But that means a user is clicking Pay twice.  Once to get me back where I can run some code, and then again when it's time to go to the payment processor for real.

I could very easily be lacking some fundamental concept and therefore my question doesn't make a lot of sense, but that's why I titled this thread the way I did.  If I return to a Controller to run some code, I wondered how I can effectively force the POST from Controller code so it's transparent to the user.  Am I explaining any better?

I thought in MVC all code is run in the Controllers, and the Views are simply to set up the page.  I don't really run server side code from the page, right?  And once I hit Submit on a POST to another website, I'm gone until the user and/or return payment information comes back.  If I wanted to do anything after the user commits to the payment, I don't know or understand how to do that.

**Additional add to the original post:**  There is a moment in time when the user clicks the submit button.  Once that's done, action transfers to the destination in the 'action' parameter and I have no opportunity to do anything until the user or the destination site responds back.  If I want to run some code after the Submit Button is clicked, how do I do that?  When I started this thread I didn't really know what code to put in this thread to explain my question, but as a result of the comments, I now think this is what I need to show from the View that the user commits from:

```
<form id="simForm" method='post' action='https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll'>
  ...all the stuff presented or included in the view for the user to make his/her decision
  <input type='submit' value="Submit Payment" class="btn btn-warning" />
</form>
```

I want to do things after the user commits, i.e. clicks the Submit Button, but it's too late once they click.  I was thinking I could have a button that says Submit Payment, but instead of POSTing to my 'action' link above, POST back to a follow-on Controller where I can execute the code I want to run after the user makes their decision and before they leave my site.  But I don't understand how to (1) initiate the real POST to the payment processor from within that follow-on Controller, or (2) force that follow-on Controller's View to execute a POST to the payment processor immediately without requiring another user action.

Now I've taken everyone on this horrible journey through my thinking, it just occurred to me what I'm wanting to do in a controller is redirect from the controller in a way that is a POST with all my page inputs to an external URL.  Is there such a method?  The only redirect I'm familiar with is for redirecting within the site.

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Alan

Comment: Not clear what your asking. Why aren't you just performing the _additional actions_ in the POST method?

Comment: Not clear about the question, Since you already can do the Post action, don't understand why in that action can not do all your request before return to client side.

Comment: Still not clear, but you can use ajax to call the method `ClearCart()` before you submit (and return a result indicating success or otherwise)

Comment: @Stephen - I'll spend some more time on Ajax for calling Controller code from within a View; I did not know I could do that.  I read about Ajax and now that you mention it in this way I conceptually understand, but I clearly haven't gotten familiar with that part yet.  I'll also add some more info to the original post above to try and break through the logjam on communicating my question better.  Thx.

Comment: @Alan, Still not sure from your edits, but if your have a submit button, you can handle its click event and call a controller method `ClearCart()` to run some code and return a value or values and based on the returned data you can cancel the post or display a message or continue with the post.

Comment: @Stephen - I'm posting below the solution I was led to.  I adjusted the title to be better focused.  Do I need to rewrite the opening post above to reduce the 'clutter' and focus on what might be a better way to express the issue?  Obviously at first I originally had trouble asking the question in a way that it was understandable.

Comment: @Alan, Leave the question as is. The comments would make no sense if you change it and it would confuse others who come across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use ajax to get back to a Controller Action, execute the code, and then let ajax finish with the Submit.  The following code seems to work fine:

The Controller:

```
Public Class MiscController
  Inherits Controller
  Public Function ActionsBeforeSubmit() As ActionResult
    ClearCart()
    Return New EmptyResult()
  End Function
End Class
```

The View:

```
<form id="simForm" method='post' target="_blank" action='https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll'>
  ...PAGE CONTENT HERE
  <input type='button' onclick="UserCommit()" value="Submit Payment" class="btn btn-warning" />
</form>

<script >
  function UserCommit() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("ActionsBeforeSubmit", "Misc")'
      async: false,
    })
    $("#simForm").submit()
  }
</script>
```

When the button is clicked, the script UserCommit() is run.  Within that script ajax runs the Controller Action ActionsBeforeSubmit.  **Updated this post:** async: false required to force Submit to wait until ActionsBeforeSubmit is done. (although some texts suggest to not use async: false)  After the Action finishes, the script performs the Submit.

Best Regards,
Alan

Comment: Alan, A few comments. 1) Use [Unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) i.e. give the button an `id` and `$('#yourButton').click(function() {...` 2) Put `$("#simForm").submit()` in the ajax `success` callback (the `submit` will occur before `ActionsBeforeSubmit` completes despite what you think you might be seeing.

Comment: @Stephen - as you see above, I updated my post.  After I exited VS and re-entered, the script ran async as originally expected.  Will study your comments. BR.